# Integrate react ace editor to react native application

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to add react ace editor to a react native application to display javascript,c,java, html, xml files, is it possible ? If it is, I want to know if the performances will be correct ? And if it's not, do you know a component or a way to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a webView in react native and render in it an index.html file
    stored locally and then put the javascript code, c code content in this html form
    including the right js libraries to obtain the right coloration for each source code.

Your html can contain either a react component if you packed it in a bundle.js.
Then you can add your source code for right coloration using ajax call from your component for exemple if the code is stored on a server returning JSON.